# "Invite your friends and colleagues" email from Careers has character problems

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email

The email telling that you "given you the ability to invite up to 5 friends and colleagues." has some characters that are not displayed well on Gmail
as you can see on the screenshot below:

[image: "Invite your friends and colleagues" email has character problems]

Comment: It's a subtle way of saying, "please only invite people who understand character encoding".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We recently fixed this bug, but after the email was sent to you. We've updated the tooling we use to extract strings for localization and a few of our files were mistakenly encoded as ASCII which caused the tooling to extract the strings as ASCII rather than UTF8. Doh!

Anyway, it's fixed now. Thanks for the report!